# Caliburn micro and tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have looked at most resources but i can find a good solution. I have a tab control HARD coded.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource SettingsTab}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SettingsTabItemStyle}" Background="WhiteSmoke" >
                <TabItem Header="ΓΕΝΙΚΑ" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" > <Grid /></TabItem>                              
                <TabItem Header="Προσωπικό" Margin="0" IsSelected="True">
                    <Grid MinHeight="400">                     

                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50,67,50,0"  Name="ActiveItem" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Τραπέζια" Margin="0">
                    <Grid />
                </TabItem>
```

**UPDATE -  Restate problem**
Here is my customized tab control. The gray text is a disabled tab item it acts like a group. Like General settings, System settings etc. So it  has a role as a navigation menu. Curently i have a content control at each tabitem (not the disabled ones) and bind the view model i want.
But i cant use Conductor.Collection.OneActive with CM.
Why?
I have seen helloscreens example from CM sample and other samples but the problem here is that if i do this via binding then there is no way to display the disabled tabitems other than creating a dummy view model that serves no purpose.So how can i achieve this ?

[image: ad]

Comment: I see, that makes sense, let me create another example.

Comment: What about this: https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmwpftabexample/src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: source [here](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmwpftabexample/src)

> I have a tab control HARD coded.

Is this a requirement?

> But i cant use Conductor.Collection.OneActive with CM. Why?

I think the reason this won't work is to use `Conductor.Collection.OneActive` you need to bind the `ItemsSource` to the Items collection.  If you're going to bind `ItemsSource` you can't also describe the tab items in `XAML`.

I created a solution that doesn't involve describing the tab items in xaml.

The key parts:

In `ShellView` the `TabControl` `ItemContainerStyle` is described to the tab items `IsEnabled` property can be bound to the view model.

```
 <TabControl x:Name="Items"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

ShellViewModel is similar but we're now activating the second view model because the first one is not enabled.

```
public class HeaderViewModel : BaseTabViewModel
    {
        public HeaderViewModel(string name)
        {
            DisplayName = name;
            IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

  public ShellViewModel(Tab2ViewModel tab2ViewModel,
                              Tab3ViewModel tab3ViewModel
            )
        {
             Items.Add (new HeaderViewModel ("ΓΕΝΙΚΑ"));
            Items.Add(tab2ViewModel);
            Items.Add(tab3ViewModel);

            ActivateItem (tab2ViewModel);
        }
```

Enable or disable the tab item in the constructor of the view model.

```
 public Tab2ViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "Προσωπικό";
            IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

The un-styled result is that the first tab item is disabled and the next two are enabled.

[image]

Comment: thank you Model.View and Bind.Model at me seem the same.  But the problem is that by using Bind.Model then Parent is nullo . Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: ok it is pretty straight forward but i have currently some dummy tab items that are disabled.I mean if i want a grouped menu it seems imposible

Comment: that i dont know how to populate my tab control as i want. I saw your example but this doesnt help because if you see my image it has some items that have enabled=false (the group )

Comment: So you want certain tab items enabled/disabled based on what?

Comment: on nothing. I just want a menu like this http://i.imgur.com/OdDb7.png . I dont know how to use a conductor with this. The problem is that i want these things with small letters.The only solution is the have at each tabitem a contentcontrol that binds to a viewModel class. If i follow your solution at bitbucket then i would get only the items with white big letters(because these only bind to a viewmodel)

Comment: So you want to see how to change the TabItem based on the selected menu item?

Comment: Ok so it seems not easy to have any other solution. Would it be ok to declare viewmodels for dummy tabs within one file ?

Comment: Yes, you could even use the BaseViewModel as the dummy instead of creating a vm just to be a dummy.

Comment: but still i have to do multiple classes? Because i dont know how i can pass instances from MEF.

Comment: Updated, you probably don't need to use MEF for that.  I updated the source and answer.